# Python-Binance how to get recent trades USDT amount

Tags: python

There is a function for that

```
client.futures_recent_trades(symbol="XRPUSDT")
```

this code shows recent trades perfectly but there is a problem with it, it only shows quantity of trade but I need usdt amount is there any other python modules for do that what should I do